# Converting a multi-callback interface to flows using callbackflow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have an Android app that uses WebRTC communication.

A major component of the WebRTC library is the `PeerConnection.Observer` interface, which looks like this:

```
public interface Observer {
    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onSignalingChange(SignalingState var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceConnectionChange(IceConnectionState var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onStandardizedIceConnectionChange(IceConnectionState newState) {}

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onConnectionChange(PeerConnectionState newState) {}

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceGatheringChange(IceGatheringState var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onIceCandidateError(IceCandidateErrorEvent event) {}

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onSelectedCandidatePairChanged(CandidatePairChangeEvent event) {}

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onAddStream(MediaStream var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onRemoveStream(MediaStream var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onDataChannel(DataChannel var1);

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    void onRenegotiationNeeded();

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver receiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) {}

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onRemoveTrack(RtpReceiver receiver) {}

    @CalledByNative("Observer")
    default void onTrack(RtpTransceiver transceiver) {}
}
```

I want to use Kotlin Flows to send and receive the ICE candidates and other "streaming"-type events.

I looked at using Kotlin's `callbackFlow` method, but all of the examples I can find describe a callback interface that only has a single callback method, allowing the interface to be implemented anonymously inside the `callbackFlow` block. In the case of the listener above, it has as many as 17 callback methods (though some are optional). Is there an easy-to-read and efficient way to make some of these methods use flows?

Comment: The sample in https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html has 3 methods that need to be implemented in that interface. So it's not just for small interfaces. If you can't squeeze the required implementation into callbackFlow directly, maybe create a class that encapsulates this interface and then exposes just a simpler callback to use inside a flow. Your interface looks like you should create multiple flows from it's events though, maybe from some central listener object or similar because a flow can have only 1 type

Comment: @zapl You've stated the issue a little better than I did: yes, the problem is that I need multiple separate flows from different events. Right now I'm creating my own smaller interfaces made of a few methods from the big interface, but that's messy.

Comment: I guess you can implement a single listener that has multiple [SharedFlows](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) for the different kinds of events, the listener then simple emits where it belongs and as long as you can reference that single listener you get access to the flow you need. Edit: StateFlow is probably bad for events, you're probably not interested in events from the past.

Answer (score 0):

As @zapl say, you can use `MutableSharedFlow` instead of `callbackFlow`, like this:

```
object RTCSDKWrapper {

    data class AddTrackR(
        RtpReceiver receiver, 
        MediaStream[] mediaStreams
    )

    private val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Any?>()

    init {
        val observer = object : Observer() {
            override fun void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver receiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    sharedFlow.emit(AddTrackR(receiver, mediaStreams))
                }
            }
        })
        // register observer
    }

    suspend fun doSomeThing(): AddTrackR? {
        var result: AddTrackR? = null
        addTrack()
        sharedFlow.filterIsInstance<AddTrackR>().take(1).collect {
            result = it
        }
        return result
    }

}
```